# Unity 2D OnTriggerEnter Not Working, Tried Everything

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

Ive been trying to find the solution to this for hours. I'm trying to learn but I've been stuck on this single problem. I have red creatures that move around randomly, and I want them to clone themselves when they collide with the green objects.
Here is the script attached to the green objects.

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Reproduction : MonoBehaviour
{

    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider col) //Ive tried 'other' also, didnt make a difference
    {
        Destroy(col.gameObject);
        Debug.Log("enter");
        //GameObject a = Instantiate(other.GameObject) as GameObject;
        //a.transform.position = new Vector2(Random.Range(-2f, 2f), Random.Range(-2f, 2f));
    }

}
```

Both have 2D colliders, Rigidbody2Ds, the colliders are the right size, `IsTrigger` is true on the food object. I have tried various combinations of dynamic and kinematic. Nothing happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you should try this one:

```cs
public void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D col)
{
    // do something..
}
```

Comment: Yes that works, thank you. I didnt realize that was even a thing.